# Setting GPIO pins on touchscreen Linux Driver

Tags: linux, kernel, gpio, drivers, touchscreen

I need to specify the GPIO pins of my `EDT-FT5206` display but I don't know where to start.

I know that the linux kernel has some specific drivers for this type of screen that are located in `"/drivers/input/touchscreen/edt-ft5x06. c"`, and that can be called by means of the modprobe command; but I don't know how to specify which pins to receive the information from.

So far I've been able to collect some documentation like the screen datasheet and some information about the driver, but I haven't been able to do much more than that.

I thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

On the end of this driver you can see the device tree match table:

```
#ifdef CONFIG_OF
static const struct of_device_id edt_ft5x06_of_match[] = {
    { .compatible = "edt,edt-ft5206", .data = &edt_ft5x06_data },
    { .compatible = "edt,edt-ft5306", .data = &edt_ft5x06_data },
    { .compatible = "edt,edt-ft5406", .data = &edt_ft5x06_data },
    { .compatible = "edt,edt-ft5506", .data = &edt_ft5506_data },
    /* Note focaltech vendor prefix for compatibility with ft6236.c */
    { .compatible = "focaltech,ft6236", .data = &edt_ft6236_data },
    { /* sentinel */ }
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, edt_ft5x06_of_match);
#endif
```

With this you can look in your board device tree for the compatible property, I'm using the `arch/arm/boot/dts/imx28tx.dts` as example that has the node:

```
polytouch: edt-ft5x06@38 {
        compatible = "edt,edt-ft5x06";
        reg = <0x38>;
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&tx28_edt_ft5x06_pins>;
        interrupt-parent = <&gpio2>;
        interrupts = <5 IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_FALLING>;
        reset-gpios = <&gpio2 6 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
        wake-gpios = <&gpio4 9 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
        wakeup-source;
    };
```

With this we can use the references used in the property `pinctrl-0` to check the pins being used by the screen:

```
 tx28_edt_ft5x06_pins: tx28-edt-ft5x06-pins@0 {
        reg = <0>;
        fsl,pinmux-ids = <
            MX28_PAD_SSP0_DATA6__GPIO_2_6 /* RESET */
            MX28_PAD_SSP0_DATA5__GPIO_2_5 /* IRQ */
            MX28_PAD_ENET0_RXD2__GPIO_4_9 /* WAKE */
        >;
        fsl,drive-strength = <MXS_DRIVE_4mA>;
        fsl,voltage = <MXS_VOLTAGE_HIGH>;
        fsl,pull-up = <MXS_PULL_DISABLE>;
    };
```

If `imx28tx` is not your board then you will have to write this configurations in your board device tree, or made a DT Overlay for touchscreen using your board GPIOs.